# Why are Firefox and Safari having problems with certain PDF files on the web?

Tags: safari, pdf, web-browsing

I'm having fits with a certain web PDF document using both Firefox and Safari.  Basically the document in question doesn't consist of one big pdf file; rather it consists of a bunch (20 or so) smaller files, one for each chapter or section, and the main page has file links to each of them.  In Firefox on a PC, clicking on the link for section 22 simply opens that PDF in the existing in-browser window.  In Safari or Firefox on Mac... it doesn't do *anything* - I can't navigate to or view section 22.  Similarly, downloading the individual files and saving them doesn't seem to work very well either, though I am thinking of downloading them and trying to re-create locally the directory/file structure the links seem to expect - still kind of a PITA.

[Link to PDF document](http://www.nrahq.org/compete/RuleBooks/HPR/hpr-index.pdf)

Does anyone know of any browser add-on or other tool that could be used to view something like this on a Mac?

Comment: Your link isn't.

Comment: whoops.  fixed the link.

Comment: Are you using Adobe's Adobe Reader plug-in with Safari and Firefox or the built-in OS X PDF viewer? (eg. Safari's built-in plugin)

Comment: I guess I'm using the built-in plug-in - the page displays in the browser window, and as far as I can tell I don't have any Adobe Acrobat Reader plug-in for either - nor can I find anything online that resembles one.  Works just fine on Windows...

Answer (score 3):

Adobe's Safari plugin for their PDF Reader doesn't work in 64 bit mode (and they don't supply a Firefox/Mac plugin at all!).

Try this [Adobe kb article](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/509/cpsid_50983.html) to see if setting 32-bit mode for Safari will work for you.  I had similar isses a while back, and I had to reinstall Reader (after upgrading to Snow Leopard) after doing this tip.

Answer (score 1):

There are some PDFs that the built-in PDF viewer can not handle - mostly using newer features available in Adobe Acrobat or linking to remote content. (This does not appear to be the case)

One option is to download and install [Adobe Reader](http://get.adobe.com/reader/) for Mac OS X which can handle these PDFs correctly. It will also install an Internet Plug-in to hand off handling of PDFs to the Adobe Reader program but you will notice a significant delay in the loading of PDFs.

The other workaround is download the other PDFs directly from the following URL:
http://www.nrahq.org/compete/RuleBooks/HPR/hpr-w##.pdf (replace the ## with 01 through 22 for each section and the ## with "Illustra" for the Illustration page and the w## with "apdx" for the appendix).

Comment: Mmmm... already had Adobe Acrobat downloaded and installed on this Macbook, and updated to the latest version.  Just on the off chance, I deleted that version from the /Applications directory, and downloaded & installed fresh.  Exited and restarted Firefox - zero change in ability to browse that document.  Can you browse the links in that file from your Mac?

Comment: So... now Safari won't open the file at all, nor hand off to Acrobat Reader - just opens a blank window, nothing else.  I'd had some other extensions loaded for being able to open PDFs in the browser window, instead of having to open them in Acrobat Reader.  I disabled those, and now Firefox will open the file and hand off to Reader... but Reader still cannot open any of the file links on that page *except* one... that I'd already downloaded directly to the same directory that the hpr-index.pdf file is in.  So *that* file is where the index is pointing to - in the same local directory.

Comment: @memilanuk Not sure. Updated my answer with how you can access the secondary files but it should technically be working. (Even with just OS X's renderer)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the way the Mac PDF viewers display links to files vs. links to URLs.

I opened your PDF in Acrobat Pro X and can see the links have an action of opening a file instead of a URL.

Modify the link properties to specify an action of "Open a web link" instead of "Open a file" and the links should work in the browser.

I modified your hpr-index.pdf and changed one of the links to open the URL: http://www.nrahq.org/compete/RuleBooks/HPR/hpr-w03.pdf
Viewing the file in Safari using the native PDF viewer opened the correct file when clicking the link in the PDF.